# How to check if a column has all increasing values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How could I, ideally with 1 table scan, determine if a column has all increasing values.  ie: 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, ...

would it need a custom function?

Comment: . . Are the values ever `NULL`?  If so, what is the behavior?

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggests an [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expression in combination with a window function (`lead()` or `lag()`) in the subquery. `EXISTS` will stop scanning as soon as the first row is found, which can be *substantially* faster with big tables:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM (SELECT col, lead(col) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS next_col FROM tbl) t
   WHERE  col >= next_col
   OR     col IS NULL
  );
```

`id` being the column that determines the order of rows.

If your condition is fulfilled (*"column has all increasing values"*) it returns `FALSE`.

While the column isn't defined `NOT NULL`, also rule out `NULL` values which would always violate your condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()` and aggregation:

```
select (case when bool_and(col > prev_col) then 'increasing'
             else 'not increasing'
         end)
from (select t.*, lag(col) over (order by ?) as prev_col
      from t
     ) t
where prev_col is not null;
```

Note that `?` is for the column in the table that specifies the ordering of the rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so such a column is needed for your question to make sense.

Comment: This returns "increasing" even when there are NULL values, which violate the given condition "all increasing".